# GCE create an instances from iso file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, disk, google-compute-disk

I'm trying to create an instance with the custom image.

First, I found that the
`gcloud compute instances import` command can create VM with the OVA file.

But I would like to create with ISO. Is there any approach to get it done? I read the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/import-existing-image), and it looks like only can create a persistent disk image from an ISO file, but I want it to be the boot disk.

Thank you.

Comment: Create a disk with the ISO, then transform the disk in image. And use that image in your compute engine.

Comment: Using an ISO image is not supported. You will need to first create a running virtual machine in your lab from the ISO and then export the VM in a supported format for import into Google Cloud. I do not recommend doing this. I recommend that you select a supported Google Cloud image and modify the VM as you desire. Then create an image from the VM.